# Is there a better site for this question?

Tags: discussion, migration, off-topic, down-votes

Wondering if I should move https://superuser.com/questions/768807/how-to-see-my-own-domain-from-host-server to another site?  Or if it belongs here, what I might do to improve it, since it is being down voted, I assume it needs improvement.

Comment: It does not belong at Superuser.  Why are you asking about a year old thread?  As indicated over a year ago, its a duplicate, of an existing question here at Superuser.

Comment: @Ramhound I'm asking because someone recently downvoted it, bringing it to my attention again.  Would like to find the proper stackexchange home for it.  If it is a duplicate, let's locate the question it duplicates.  Got downvoted twice today, so would like to improve it or move it.  I didn't move it here, someone at serverfault did.